# delete comment from facebook plugin if it is deleted on facebook wall

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-comments

Are comments on fb wall and on some web page synced? What I want to be:

1. someone leaves a comment on a site and checks "Post to my wall" option;
2. comment appears on his/her wall;
3. then he/she deletes comment from the wall;
4. comment is not being deleted on the site.

Am I doing anything wrong and this functionality already implemented by fb, so I am using the facebook comment plugin improperly?
Is it a correct approach in general? I mean - if I do everything ok, there is a reason why comments are not being deleted from a web page if they are deleted from the wall.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the plugin and the user's wall are not linked. The comment post and wall post have different Object IDs and the wall post is merely a copy of the original comment. In theory, these should be synched up, but Facebook hasn't built it in that way.

You will have to use the API to detect deleted comments and remove them from the comment plugin if you want them synched. But really, the user should be responsible for removing their comment as they must have removed it for a reason.